# Ubuntu 22.04 Lock Screen is changing the brightness level automatically - Asus Vivobook

Tags: screen, brightness, asus

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my new laptop Asus Vivobook Pro 15 OLED. I noticed a weird behavior when the screens goes locked, the brightness level is automatically increased when the screen turns on back again. I also noticed that the file /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/actual_brightness is automatically changed to a higher level that the one that I had before the screen went locked.

I appreciate your help if someone has had this issue or a similar one.

Comment: It is a known bug (kernel + systemd) with some AMD GPU. There are some workarounds. I was affected too, but it was solved with the 5.15 kernel.

Comment: Thank you Pilot6, effectively I found out this issue with kernel 5.15.0-40. I had to rollback to version 5.15.0-25 and it was fixed.

Comment: Please report it to Launchpad by `ubuntu-bug linux`. This should be fixed. Mark it as a regression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue happens with kernel 5.15.0-40. I rolled back to 5.15.0-25 and is fixed. So it was introduced in the upper minor version # 40 of the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my hp omen 15(2019) laptop, with Nvidia GeForce GTX 1660Ti. After I changed GPU drivers from open-source Nouveau to proprietary NVIDIA drivers 535, the problem was gone. Maybe helpful for some guys.